# Kernel - Finding written block numbers

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Is there any way in the kernel to get a list of blocks that have been physically written to and the order in which they were written?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is a little vague - Which blocks are you referring to? Memory pages, hard disk sectors, ???

Comment: Sorry -- hard disk. I thought I've come across a command you can run where you can view written blocks but can't recall if that's correct or what the command is in linux. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `blktrace` can produce this information.

Comment: +1, though it does get a little flakey when dealing with device mapper and write barriers (or at least it did mid last year when I was using it) .. to discover that device mapper had issues with write barriers in certain situations.

Comment: I'm actually trying to find a way to do this in the kernel programmatically. I want to get block numbers as they are written to from within the linux kernel source code.